# How to resolve "An error occurred while deserializing input data." when sending XML to an asp net core web api?

Tags: xml, asp.net-core

Controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AodsController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    public async Task Post([FromBody]TestDto model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return "you did it";
    }
}
```

TestDto

```
public sealed class TestDto
{
    public string[] TestValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm posting this in the body

```
<TestDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <TestValue>
                <string>T1</string>
                <string>T</string>
        </TestValue>
</TestDTO>
```

And in `Startup.cs` I have this line

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Postman gives me this errror

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|14250dd4-4d75412529990287.",
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "An error occurred while deserializing input data."
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `XmlAttributes` and it can work.Here is a demo:

TestDto:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TestDTO")]
    public sealed class TestDto
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "TestValue")]
        public List<string> TestValue { get; set; }
    }
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/xml")]
        public void Post([FromBody] TestDto model)
        {

        }
```

startup:

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

result:
[image]